# text file statistics and problems displaying them

Tags: c, file, text

I am working on an assignment for class and we basically have to prompt a user to input two text files. The program should then read the files, display them, and also display the separate file statistics.

I have been working on the code and seem to have hit a brick wall. I can only seem to display the statistics for the second text file; moreover, the text from said file doesn't seem to be getting displayed.

Very confused indeed, so any help will be hugely appreciated. I am still really struggling with this class, despite my efforts. :(

Anyway, the code (a total mess I am sure):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {


FILE *fp;
char ch;
int lineCount, wordCount, charCount;

char filename[50], filename2[50];

lineCount = 0;
wordCount = 0;
charCount = 0;


printf("Enter a filename: ");

gets(filename);

    fp=fopen(filename, "r");

if(fp==NULL) {

printf("Error!\n");

return 1;

}

while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {

putchar(ch);

}

fclose(fp);

printf("\n");

printf("Enter a second filename: ");

gets(filename2);

    fp=fopen(filename2, "r");

if(fp==NULL) {

printf("Error!\n");

return 1;

}

while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
   if ( fp )
   {
       while ((ch=getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n') { ++charCount; }
           if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') { ++wordCount; }
           if (ch == '\n') { ++lineCount; }
           }

       if (charCount > 0) {
        ++lineCount;
        ++wordCount;
       }
    }

    printf("Lines counted: %d \n", lineCount);
    printf("Words counted: %d \n", wordCount);
    printf("Characters counted: %d \n", charCount);

getchar();

putchar(ch);

}

fclose(fp);

printf("\n");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. And please format your code in a consistent manner. And consider  to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop reads & displays the first file, not attempting to either collect or report any statistics; your second loop reads, collects & reports statistics, but does not attempt to display.

My suggestions would be to write a function to do all of this for a single file, and then call it once for each file you wish so processed.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a go. Functions, however, are where I started to really struggle with this  module. Up until then I understood what I had been learning. Will keep trying though.
Thanks again Scott. :)